# mariadb innodb engine full text search problem

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, mariadb

`create table test_fts(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 varchar(250),
    col2 text DEFAULT NULL,
    col3 varchar(250),
    FULLTEXT KEY keyword_full_text (col1,col2,col3),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)) engine=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

```
insert into test_fts(col1,col2,col3) values('hasan-new','test','hasan uçak');
insert into test_fts(col1,col2,col3) values('hasan-new','','hasan uçak');
insert into test_fts(col1,col2,col3) values('hasan-new11','test','hasan uçak');
```

i do full text search 

`SELECT *
FROM test_fts WHERE 
( MATCH (col1,col2,col3) AGAINST ('+\"hasan uçak\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  )`

result is

1   hasan-new   test    hasan uçak
2   hasan-new       hasan uçak
3   hasan-new11 test    hasan uçak

no problem.

i recreate full text index 

`alter table test_fts drop index keyword_full_text;
alter table test_fts add FULLTEXT INDEX keyword_full_text(col1, col2, col3);`

1   hasan-new   test    hasan uçak
3   hasan-new11 test    hasan uçak

one row was lost 
why ?

when i using null value instead empty string, no problem

when anyone value of columns is empty string in index fields
  , i could get this row.
Mysql can't push columns which after empty string column, value  to index data is it?

Comment: MySQL does not need backslashes there.  Perhaps the software calling MySQL does?  Try it without backslashes.

Comment: There is not solution.this is bug.https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92240